Draw Primitives using SharpDX.Direct3D9 with C# .NET Framework
I have a question, How to draw primitives? draw lines, rectangles, circles, text, etc...
For now I can draw text and Lines:
SharpDX.Direct3D9.Font
SharpDX.Direct3D9.Line
However, those lines look ugly, How can I soften the lines? ,How can I draw circles? To draw rectangles should I do it with lines? How can I draw a thick line?
I attach an image:


Why D3D9? I'd recommend using a more modern API if you can. For example, D3D11 will work with Direct2D, which does handle rendering of those sorts of primitive shapes.

@Adam I plan to add to my library, auxiliary drawing methods, the typical ones, Circles, rectangles, text, lines, triangles.
from dx9 to dx12, opengl and vulkan. I'm starting with dx9, I thought it would be easy, but I couldn't find examples.

You should elaborate on what devices and operating systems you want to target. There are easier ways to get beyond where you are now; e.g. WPF and UWP. Which include their own "community libraries".

If it is an external alternative, for example for an external overlay I would use windowsforms, but my library hooks graphics internally from the games, for example if I want to make an ESP, I must at least be able to draw rectangles.
I even thought about drawing shapes with GDI and passing that shape to a png and uploading it later as a texture. That's what I did to be able to draw text in OpenGL.

If its rectangles you want, UWP and WPF are full of rectangles (the "bounding box"). You can "animate" rectangles: move along a path; rotate; skew; resize. That's just the beginnig. "Rectangles" can contain other rectangles ... and images ("textures").

Yes, I know, but what I need is something entirely Internal using SharpDX - Direct3D9.

Well, you can now draw primitives, all with lines, and using mathematics.
(I tried to place the code here, but it is bugged, but it shows me everything wrong.)
Here I show how I did it:
Source
I guess now I have to do some kind of smoothing, anti-Aliasing or whatever it's called, so that the lines don't look pixelated.

